# Remove end of line characters from stdout? Multiple lines into a single line

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a script which outputs the following text. This is the output from a [Netopia 2210-02 ADSL2](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/DSL-Modems-and-Gateways/Netopia-ADSL2plus-Modem-2210-US-EN) modem.

```
ADSL Line State:        Up
ADSL Startup Attempts:  1
ADSL Modulation:        DMT
ADSL Data Path:         Fast
Datapump Version:       DSP 7.2.3.0, HAL 7.2.1.0
SNR Margin:                   8.20        9.00 dB
Line Attenuation:            57.50       31.00 dB
Output Power:                17.09       12.34 dBm
Errored Seconds:                 0           0
Loss of Signal:                  0         476
Loss of Frame:                   0           0
CRC Errors:                  57921         416
Data Rate:                    2880        1024
```

How can I remove the end-of-line character for each line? I would like the output to look something like this (Yes it's ugly):

```
ADSL Line State:        Up ADSL Startup Attempts:  1 ADSL Modulation:        DMT ADSL Data Path:         Fast Datapump Version:       DSP 7.2.3.0, HAL 7.2.1.0 SNR Margin:                   8.20        9.00 dB Line Attenuation:            57.50       31.00 dB Output Power:                17.09       12.34 dBm Errored Seconds:                 0           0 Loss of Signal:                  0         476 Loss of Frame:                   0           0 CRC Errors:                  57921         416 Data Rate:                    2880        1024
```

I tried some solutions like this, but they don't work:

```
# (This simply outputs the contents of the script, unmodified)
stefanl@hosta:~/Work/Cacti $ ./script | sed -e 's/$//'
```

I also tried using `tr`. I was expecting the following command to replace each newline character with the space character. This would take the multiple lines and combine them into one long single line. Instead, this only displays the last line of output. It seems to overwrite each subsequent line with the next line of output.

```
stefanl@hosta:~/Work/Cacti $ ./script | tr '\n' ' '
Data Rate:                    2880        1024stefanl@hosta:~/Work/Cacti $
stefanl@hosta:~/Work/Cacti $
```

**Update**:

Upon further examination, it looks like each line is preceded by a return character. This shows up as `^M` when using `less`. So, I added two `tr` statements. One to delete newline characters, one to delete the return character.

```
./script | | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\r'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sed` won't work (easily) because it operates on lines one at a time; you could do it, but it would involve copying the whole input into the hold buffer

`tr` actually should work the way you pasted it; are you sure the newlines are `\n`s? You can simplify it a bit by deleting the newlines instead of converting them to spaces:

```
tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Both `tr '\n' ' '` and `tr -d '\n'`
 will wrap the line in a weird way. I updated my question to show the results. So, maybe I need to use `tr`, but I just need to figure out how to use use it properly.

Comment: Could you expand on what is weird about it?  The reason your prompt is ending up on the same line as the last line of output is precisely because you have removed the '\n' at the end of the line.  If you describe the end result you are going for, I'm sure someone will come up with the appropriate filter.

Comment: Ok, I guess I could be more clear. I was hoping to wrap these multiple lines into a single line. I would expect `tr '\n' ' '` to remove the newline character and replace it with a space character, and therefore have one long line.

Comment: @Steven : I updated my question to discuss what I was expecting to see, and what was actually printed to the screen.

Comment: Hmm. Unless your output isn't ended with \n's this should give you the output you are expecting.  Have you tried piping it into a file and then confirming that the line wrapping isn't something that your term is doing for you?

Comment: I’ve been using a convoluted `sed` solution (with loops) for years. Doh!

Comment: wow! useful dude!

Answer (score 6):

besides `tr`, some other methods you can use

awk

```
awk '1' ORS= file
```

shell

```
while read -r line; do printf "%s " "$line"; done <file
```

sed

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N;s/\n/ /;ba' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr -s '\n'` to replace sequences of repeated newline characters with a single occurrence of newline.

Example:

```
>>> echo -e "Squeeze\n\n\nthose\n\n\n\nnewlines\n"
Squeeze


those



newlines

2z [franck:~] $ 
>>> echo -e "Squeeze\n\n\nthose\n\n\n\nnewlines\n" | tr -s '\n'
Squeeze
those
newlines
```

(see `man tr`)

Answer (score 0):

To remove newline characters, it's `tr -d '\n' < file`. However, to join all lines, that's `paste -sd '\0' file`.

`tr -d '\n'` produces non-text output as it doesn't terminate the one line with a newline character.

To remove, all the CR characters, you can do:

```
tr -d '\r' < file | paste -sd '\0' -
```

To only remove the CR characters that are at the end of the lines:

```
CR=$(printf '\r')
sed "s/$CR\$//" < file | paste -sd '\0' -
```

Or use `awk` for everything:

```
awk '{gsub(/\r$/, ""); printf "%s", $0} 
     END {if (NR) print ""}' < file
```

Or use `dos2unix` (which would remove those trailing CRs and also fix some other issues with text files from Microsoft OSes):

```
 dos2unix < file | paste -sd '\0' -
```