# Replace VI macro with Linux equivalent

Tags: linux, awk, sed, vi

My file arrives on a Linux server and contains `^M` characters when seen in VI and the file format = unix, `(ff=unix)`

I want to turn lines 1-4 into line lines 9 - 10.
[image]

My vi macro solves my problem.
`/\r/\rxJ`

It finds  and removes the `^M` and then joins the line to previous line.

How can I accomplish this in sed, awk or some Unix utility?

Comment: It's actually https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/150248/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3297/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193389/5132 that cover _this_ ground.  (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
awk -vORS= '{print sub(/\r$/,"") ? $0" " : $0"\n"}' < infile > outfile

awk 'ORS = sub(/\r$/,"") ? " " : "\n"' < infile > outfile

perl -pe 's/\r\n/ /' < infile > outfile
```

or in place:

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n/ /' -i file
```